# Spring locale resolver - current locale in url

Tags: spring-mvc, localization, locale, interceptor

I use this simple configuration

```
    <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:localization/messages" />
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </beans:bean>

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </beans:bean>
    </interceptors>

    <beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
        <beans:property name="cookieMaxAge" value="100000" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Works nice but what if someone will send an url to someone else? This works only with a client browser, If user changes a localization, it will set a cookie. I have seen a lot of websites that they have a localization after the first slash in the url (e.g. `nette.org/en/about`). When someone send this link, it will resolve localization depending on url. Does exist any simple solution to do this in spring framework? Somehow map this place in url?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of **CookieLocaleResolver** use **SessionLocaleResolver**.

```
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>
```

I think this should resolve your problem.

Cheers.

Comment: And what is the difference? Maybe is not clear from my post what is my goal. Someone is viewing my page in "de" locale and he want to send url to someone else but page will be shown in default locale (en) to someone who opened this url and that is what I don't want. I want to open a page in the same locale (de). Your solution not resolve this.

Comment: Only solution for this is to get a locale in url and my question was if this can be simply done with spring, I mean some interceptor, which adds current locale into all urls.

Comment: I tried your solution, when I click on link to change language, I'll get `?lang=de` in url, but this parameter disappears when I'll go into other page. How can be done what I described with your solution? Simply exchange CookieLocaleResolver for SessionLocaleResolver didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes the parameter won't come in each and every url by default. You need to do that manually. Otherwise it won't come in every url.